# How to use an On Click Listener to go to a different xml layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I have my code set up to go to the xml layout entitled getfinal when the getFin button is clicked. But my application crashes whenever I click that button. Is setContentview the wrong command to use in that situation? If so, how can i go to a new xml layout on a button click?

```
package wilson.GC;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class GradeCalculatorActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button getEx, getFin;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getEx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getexambutton);
    getFin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getfinalbutton);
    getFin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.getfinal);
            double q1, q2, ex, fin;
             EditText etq1, etq2, eteg;
             etq1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                q1 = Double.parseDouble(etq1.getText().toString());
             etq2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                q2 = Double.parseDouble(etq2.getText().toString());
             eteg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                ex = Double.parseDouble(eteg.getText().toString());

            fin = 0.4*q1+0.4*q2+0.2*ex;
                if(fin == (int)fin){
                    System.out.println((int)fin);
                }
                else{
                    fin = 0.01*((int)(fin*100));
                    System.out.println(fin);
                } 
            TextView tvfin = null;
            tvfin.setText(fin+"");
            tvfin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfinalgrade);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Let me know if you need the code for both xml pages.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use `setContentView()` twice for the same Activity. It is better you make a completely new Activity and assign getFinal layout to it using `setContentView()`. OPen that Activity in `onClick()` of the button using an Intent.

Answer (score 2):

Move your layout getfinal.xml into a ViewSwitcher that resides in the main.xml. And in the onClick simply switch the layout using the ViewSwitchers showNext() method.

The layout file could look something like this (sudo code).

```
 <ViewSwitcher android="@+id/switcher>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/first_layout"> ... first content with button ... </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/second_layout"> ... content to show when pressed... </LinearLayout>
 </ViewSwitcher>
```

Then do:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  getEx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getexambutton);
  switch = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
  getFin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getfinalbutton);
  getFin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch.showNext();
        .....  
    });
```